# Flutter - Polylines redrawing to the shortest path

Tags: flutter, dart, location, maps, google-polyline

I'm facing a curious problem regarding Polylines on Flutter using the ***google_map_polyline*** package.

When i'm going for a walk and start the route (using the ***Location*** package to ensure updated coordinates) the polylines keep drawing without problem if the route is a straight line or get far away from the destination.

However, if my route try do go around back to the starting point, at some point, all the polyline drawn is redrawed considering my current point and the shortest path to the origin point, like if i've made another path (the shortest to my current point).

Somebody already faced something like this?

Thanks.

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say that there is a bug in how you are determining how to draw the current route. It's near impossible to say without seeing any code, though. In fairness, however, you are using a third-party Google Maps package whose latest version is 0.2.0+1 and has been marked as officially discontinued. It's not only possible for it to be buggy - I would expect it to be.

Comment: @Abion47 as i said, i'm using the **google_map_polyline** to generate the polylines and set it to the GoogleMap object (the Polylines package uses a starting and end points to calculate the path to be draw). Maybe this is a bug, because the path is totally redraw if my current position gets near the starting position (so, i can't do a circular route and expect a "circle" drawn because when i'me getting near the starting point, the route is redrawn to the shortest path).

Comment: If all you are doing is providing a start and end point, then it sounds like the bug might be your doing. I haven't used this package, but it sounds like it constructs lines that formulate the shortest distance between the two points given. That means if you walk in a circle, the shortest distance between your start and your current position will not reflect your overall path once you pass roughly the halfway point. Do get this to work the way you want, you will need to take periodic samples of the current position and draw the polylines multiple times to show the full path.